# CSV with headers to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv to a xml.
CSV sample

```
ID;name;addresses;street;streetNR
1;peter;;streetTest;58784
1;peter;;street2;04512
```

this should look like

```
<ID>
<name>Peter</name>
<addresses>
<address>
<street>streetTest</street>
<plz>58784</plz>
</address>
<address>
<street>street2</street>
<plz>04512</plz>
</address>
</address>
</ID>
```

The file XML is huge. It's around 100 tags. What is the smartest way to do this? I already checked the forum but can't find something that fits well enough.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There are a *lot* of ways to read CSVs, a lot of ways to write XML and what "the smartest" is depends on what each developer wants. Easiest? Fastest? Cleanest? Using minimal memory? Some of those requirements contradict each other. As for 100 tags - that's actually a small XML file

Comment: If you read the CSV data into objects using either custom code or one of the many CSV libraries you can serialize it to XML using one of .NET's serializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XElement` and `Linq` to convert the csv with header to xml

```
var header = File.ReadLines(inputfile).First().Split(';'); //Read header
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputfile).Skip(1); //Skip header row        

//format the xml how you want
var xml = new XElement("EmpDetails", 
    lines.Select(line => new XElement("Item",
        line.Split(';').Select((column, index) => new XElement(header[index], column)))));

xml.Save(outputfile); //output xml file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<root></root>");
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);
            int rowCount = 0;
            string[] headers = null;
            string line = "";
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>(); ;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (++rowCount == 1)
                {
                    headers = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string[]>(splitArray[0], splitArray));

                }
            }

            var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                int groupCount = 0;
                XElement addresses = null;
                foreach (var row in group)
                {
                    string[] colData = row.Value;
                    if (++groupCount == 1)
                    {
                        XElement xGroup = new XElement("ID", new object[] {
                            new XElement("name", colData[1]),
                            new XElement("addresses")
                        });
                        root.Add(xGroup);
                        addresses = xGroup.Element("addresses");

                    }
                    int min = Math.Min(headers.Length, colData.Length);
                    XElement address = new XElement("address");
                    addresses.Add(address);
                    for (int i = 3; i < min; i++)
                    {
                        XElement xCol = new XElement(headers[i], colData[i]);
                        address.Add(xCol);
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Material
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public List<Property> properties { get; set; }
    }
    public class Property
    {
        public string property { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```